# a path to v+ing / a path to + verb

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, nouns, prepositions

Which one is grammatically correct?

> 1. an auspicious path to fighting against rape.
> 2. an auspicious path to fight rape.

or maybe

> 3. an auspicious path towards the fight against rape

Comment: Both are grammatical. The first is a path at the end of which lies a fight against rape; the second is a path by which one may fight rape.

Comment: I think this use of ***auspicious*** is bordering on archaic. It's usually only used today of ***signs, early indications*** which are *strongly indicative of future success*. So a path or plan may have an *auspicious start* if it causes or coincides with reactions or events that seem to favour the success of the cause, but the plan itself wouldn't normally be thus labelled.

Comment: Yeah, I agree... "auspicious" was the thing that tripped me up here...  "Direct", (or, something like it) would probably make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

All are correct grammatically.

On an unrelated note, I would argue that the use of the word "fight" in the context of the subject matter is probably counterproductive to the cause.

> an auspicious path for rape prevention